# Grant microphone access to terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions

Apparently VS Code does not ask for microphone or camera permissions according to this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95062#).

I hope to work around this issue by granting access to the microphone and camera directly via terminal.

The problem is, I don't know how to do that. Starting programs via terminal does not do the trick - that way only the startet programs ask for permissions. I read a couple times now that permissions can be granted directly to there terminal - but I can't find an explanation how.

The problem is, I cannot grant the permissions before the terminal actively asks for them.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer, you could try this
https://superuser.com/questions/1441270/apps-dont-show-up-in-camera-and-microphone-privacy-settings-in-macbook

You might want to add "sudo" in front of your command to perform it as root which might get around some permissions.

Comment: Nope, I found that during my research, too. Thats not the point and messing with a lot of permission settings. If you look at the comments below the accepted answer in your link, I'm not alone with that point of view. This "solution" does not target the terminal specifically. But  I appreciate your effort ;)

Comment: Already thought you might have already. It was worth the try. I'm not sure, but it wouldn't be weird to me if apple blocked this, or there might be some hash linking happening since I couldn't find anything other than the link up here that was useful. Good luck though!